# How to print clickable URL as output using normal print statement in python

Tags: python, passwords, password-strength

I was making a password generator in python. The password generating part works perfectly, but I need to check the strength of generated password using `example.com`
My doubt is how do I print it to the output screen using the standard print function or with some other codes in python

ps: I like to have the least number of codes, now the code has 8 sloc

Comment: do you want the link to show as a link or do you want its content in your terminal ?

Comment: @mrCopiCat I want the program to show a clickable link so that user can check the password strength if he/she likes to

Comment: well in the terminal it is by default shown as a clickable link when you print it (but you need to add the https, try with this example : `print("https://example.com")` ). It isnt always the case on any terminal but it mostly is.